# Unity cant resolve extension type name in configuration file

Tags: unity-container

I have one project where this is working, and one where it isn't. I can't spot any differences, my namespace is correct, the assembly name is correct. What is the issue?

Config file:

```
   <unity>
        <containers>
          <container>
            <extensions>
              <add type="XIV.Initialization.Configuration.InitializationContainerExtension, XIV.Initialization" />
            </extensions>
          </container>
        </containers>
      </unity>
```

The error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias XIV.Initialization.Configuration.InitializationContainerExtension, XIV.Initialization could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed a reference to the assembly in my config file, /facepalm